How to plot temperature dependent Phonon dispersion using Quantum Espresso?
Would someone please suggest me how can I plot temperature dependent phonon dispersion using Quantum Espresso? The paper (10.48550/arXiv.2211.15571) plotted phonon dispersion at different temperatures (Fig 1b) and mentioned that
"For phonons, we apply a Temperature Dependent Effective Potential method (TDEP) that uses all steps in NVT simulations to construct an effective harmonic force constants (HFCs) that can best describe the potential landscape at certain T. This effective HFCs then intrinsically includes the effect of anharmonic phonon-phonon interactions on the phonon frequency and renormalize the phonon energies. Note that the structure at certain T is the relaxed structure. Fig. 1(b) presents our calculated phonon dispersions at a function of temperature using the effective
HFCs."
For me the procedures look difficult as I am not familiar with VASP and AIMD. I have gone through the TDEP method (https://tdep-developers.github.io/tdep/) where input files preparation depends on VASP.
So, Are there any procedures I can follow to plot the temperature dependent phonon dispersion using Quantum Espresso? I want to share one idea, please suggest me if it looks OK to you.

Run CPMD in QE (NPT ensemble) and get atomic structure at certain Temperature (Temp1)
Relax the atoms positions (pw.x, relax.in). But the cell structure would not be relaxed as the structure get from CPMD simulation at the Temp1 keep same in all of the consecutive runs.
Finally, run ph.x,q2r.x and matdyn.x to get the phonon dispersion at the TempT1

The procedures I described above based on QE, are OK to you?
Thank you!

Take a look at alamode: https://alamode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html
